# Optimum equals extremum?

Tags: soft-question, terminology

Is there any difference between optimum and extremum?

It seems to me that they are the same. Am I right?

Comment: In many contexts, they are the same, but there may be contexts in which they are not. Please provide more information.

Comment: In optimization.

Comment: You've just changed an adjective to the related verb. Optimization *of what*? Context, please.

Comment: Oops. That should be "noun," not "adjective," but my point stands.

Answer (score 0):

An "optimal" value is usually an extremum (of *something*), but an extremum may not be optimal. For example, "lowest possible profit" is an extremum, but is pessimal rather than optimal.